# Java, local variable increasing its value without any reason

Tags: java, variables

I have small method that should compute the size of a directory:

```
private static long getDirSize(File srcDir) {
    if (srcDir.isFile()) {
        sum += srcDir.length();
    } else {
        for (File curFile : srcDir.listFiles()) {
            getDirSize(curFile);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

`sum` is a class variable.

Whenever my program steps over the `if` statement, `sum` increases its value. I tried setting a breakpoint on the `sum +=` line, but even though the value of `sum` increases, execution never stops there.

If I delete the `sum +=` line then `sum` never changes, so I'm sure that this line is where `sum` is being increased.

What could be going on?

Comment: This might seem like a stupid question, but have you started you application in a Debug mode and double checked if breakpoint is inserted in this exact line?

Comment: do your breakpoints work on other lines?

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the same `sum` variable? Do you have a member variable named `sum`? Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the first line in the method, and stepping through it?

Comment: Voting to close.  This required a MCVE.  And in fact the creation of the MCVE would have revealed the fact that the problem was not in this code ... but in some code in another thread that was setting `sum` to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps another thread is messing with that variable. With a very simple change, you can make this thread-safe, and get back your sanity too:

```
private static long getDirSize(File srcDir) {
    long sum = 0;
    if (srcDir.isFile()) {
        sum += srcDir.length();
    } else {
        for (File curFile : srcDir.listFiles()) {
            sum += getDirSize(curFile);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This is the right way to calculate the size. However, it would not have solved the OP's actual problem ... but that problem was not diagnosable / solvable based on the information in the Question.